# Labelled nodes in RaphaelJS for graph-theory graphs

Tags: javascript, graph, raphael, graph-theory

I am trying RaphaelJS for drawing graph theory style graphs. For example:

[image]

While it is easy to create circles/nodes in RaphaelJS, I haven't figured out how to associate each node with a label (and having the label inside each node).

Is this feasible with RaphaelJS?

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) from the raphael page. Without looking at the code you see that he somehow  managed to associate them.

Comment: @DanLee, I've seen this one before but there is no label.

Comment: How dynamic will these nodes and their interconnectability be?  Adding labels is actually reasonably easy if you're rolling your own -- you simply need to print a paper.text atop each node and apply your click handlers, if any, to both the node and the text label.  Such a thing would be easy to write a class for in Raphael...

Comment: @KevinNielsen, the nodes are all static in the sense that once they are drawn they will stay as they are. The connections between the nodes are not very dense either. Could you please provide a more detailed explanation (a link will help too) for what you've proposed? Thanks!

Comment: check out [Dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/). it may suit your needs.

Comment: @EliranM. thanks for the suggestion! I took a look but there are two main problems: 1. the edges are not straight lines; 2. the labels seem can only be outside the node (from the comments by others on the front page).

Comment: it's all customizable. see [this graph](http://www.cloudifysource.org/guide/2.1/monitoring/the_web_management_console.html) ("applications view" area) i've made based on dracula. as can be seen, all nodes has custom renderers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write a little bit of code to manage a series of such nodes using default styles, allowing for overrides as desired.

```
// "Constructor" -- accepts a Raphael paper to use as background object and default values for node radius, node style, and label style.
function NodeManager( paper, node_radius, node_style, label_style )
{
    this.paper = paper;
    this.nodes = {};
    this.node_radius = node_radius || 24;
    this.node_style = node_style || { fill: 'white', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 3 };
    this.label_style = label_style || { fill: 'black', stroke: 'none', 'font-family': 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif', 'font-size': 32, 'font-weight': 600 };
}

// Add a node to the paper.  
// Code is an arbitrary or symbolic name; 
// x and y are the coordinates the node is centered on; 
// label is the node's textual content (no clipping is performed, so be careful!); 
// node_radius, node_style, and label_style are optional, and can be used to override the appearance of this node.
NodeManager.prototype.addNode = function addNode( code, x, y, label, node_radius, node_style, label_style )
{
    var node = this.paper.circle( x, y, node_radius || this.node_radius ).attr( node_style || this.node_style );
    var label_object = this.paper.text( x, y, label ).attr( label_style || this.label_style );
    this.nodes[code] =
        {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            r: node_radius || this.node_radius,
            node: node,
            label: label_object
        };
}

// Connect the nodes corresponding to the two given codes.  connection_style can be used to override the appearance of the connective link, but the default node_style will be used if it isn't specified.
NodeManager.prototype.connectNodes = function connectNodes( code1, code2, connection_style )
{  
    var angle = Math.atan2(this.nodes[code2].y - this.nodes[code1].y, this.nodes[code2].x - this.nodes[code1].x );      //  this will be the angle from point to point
    var inverse_angle = angle + Math.PI;

    ox1 = this.nodes[code1].x + Math.cos( angle ) * this.nodes[code1].r;
    oy1 = this.nodes[code1].y + Math.sin( angle ) * this.nodes[code1].r;

    ox2 = this.nodes[code2].x + Math.cos( inverse_angle ) * this.nodes[code2].r;
    oy2 = this.nodes[code2].y + Math.sin( inverse_angle ) * this.nodes[code2].r;

    var pathstr = "M" + ox1 + "," + oy1 + " L" + ox2 + "," + oy2;

    var path = this.paper.path( pathstr ).attr( connection_style || this.node_style );
}
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/L4A2F/) to see a little example of the results.